# OpenGL Segmentation Fault after typing glBegin()

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault

I'm very new to programming in OpenGL, and all was fine until I received segmentation fault out of nowhere and now cannot get rid of it. Can anyone spot the segmentation fault and explain it to me?

Note: Though it's for an assignment, I'm not here looking for answers. In fact, I won't even mention the assignment details or even send full code (though, the following code also results in segfault):

```
#  include <stdio.h>
#  include <stdlib.h>
#  ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#  include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#  else
#  include <GL/gl.h>
#  include <GL/glu.h>
#  include <GL/freeglut.h>
#  endif
#  include <iostream>
#  include <ctime>
#  include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define GRID 50 

/* Eye location */
float eye[]={5,5,5};

void initDefaults(void){
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glFrustum(-10,10,-10,10,0,100);
    gluPerspective(45,1,1,100);
}

/* TEMPORARY */
void createGrid(){  

//After checking, I narrowed down the segmentation fault to here.   
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    printf("help");
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(25,25,25);
    glEnd();
}

/* displays UI to user */
void display(void){

    //Clears the board upon (re)display
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Enables backface culling
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    //Sets up the perspective matrix (viewing/camera)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2], GRID/2, GRID/2, 0, 0, 1, 0); 

    //I believe the segmentation fault occurs in here.
    //************************************
    createGrid();
    //************************************

    //Used for double-buffering
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

/* main function - program entry point */
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);                                      
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow("Terrain");                                
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);                         
    gluOrtho2D(-1, GRID + 1, -1, GRID + 1);
    initDefaults();
    glutMainLoop();                                             
    return(0);                                                  
}
```

Comment: Consider using shaders, they make larger projects possible. freeglut is my favorite library btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

Double check your development environment. Your code (so far) is perfectly fine and what you experience could be caused by mismatching libraries. For example if you're developing on Linux the `libGL.so` must exactly match the GPU driver and version (or a purely indirect GLX context being used, which normally happens only for remote X11).